# Ag-grid batch calls for data loading

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using ag-grid for display. I don't want to bring complete data in one go. 
e.g. i want to bring 11-20th page data when user on 10th page
How can i implement ?

Comment: remove server side pagination, all the data will be loaded at one time in client side.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for help in asking a useful question.

Comment: @Niladri I want to avoid data loading in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to [Ag-grid infinite scrolling row model](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#turning-on-infinite-scrolling).

For more details on [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) row models, visit documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-models/

> i want to bring 11-20th page data when user on 10th page

I  hope you mean to load 11-20th records when user scrolls to see 10th record.
For that, 
set parameters `maxBlocksInCache`, `cacheBlockSize = 10` (to make cache block size 10), `infiniteInitialRowCount` accordingly.

---

### Update

As per [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pagination/)

> In v9.0 ag-Grid pagination changed from server side pagination to
>   client side pagination. Server side pagination was then removed in
>   v10.1.
>
> If you were doing server side pagination, we recommend moving to
>   pagination with infinite scrolling as a way of migration to the new
>   mechanism.
>
> If you were slicing manually the data in your Datasource to mimic
>   pagination done in the browser only, we recommend that you use the
>   default In Memory Row Model and set the row data as normal and then
>   set grid property pagination=true.

Comment: Thank you @Paritosh but i want to have pagination as well is there any another way ?